# Is there any difference between these 2 code?

Tags: python, for-loop, variables, syntax

Which way is the better to use for loop?

Should i define the variable before using it in for loop or it's also okay to use it without defining?

```
test_list = get_list()

for value in test_list:
  pass
```

or

```
for value in get_list():
  pass
```

Comment: One is more readable, the other is more efficient (less memory?). This is an opinionated question.

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: it depends, if You are not going to use it a lot You can use the function directly, however if You need to reuse the variable You should make the function return a variable.

Comment: `for value in get_list()` will only call `get_list()` once, if that is what you want to know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They're going to be equivalent. Python won't call `get_list()` during every iteration, only for the first.

Answer (score 0):

To compare codes and understand how it is byte compiled, you can use the [dis](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html) module.

```
import dis

code1 = """
test_list = get_list()

for value in test_list:
  pass
"""

code2 = """
for value in get_list():
  pass
"""

print("code1:")
dis.dis(code1)

print("code2:")
dis.dis(code2)
```

You get:

```
code1:
  2           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (get_list)
              2 CALL_FUNCTION            0
              4 STORE_NAME               1 (test_list)

  4           6 SETUP_LOOP              12 (to 20)
              8 LOAD_NAME                1 (test_list)
             10 GET_ITER
        >>   12 FOR_ITER                 4 (to 18)
             14 STORE_NAME               2 (value)

  5          16 JUMP_ABSOLUTE           12
        >>   18 POP_BLOCK
        >>   20 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             22 RETURN_VALUE

code2:
  2           0 SETUP_LOOP              14 (to 16)
              2 LOAD_NAME                0 (get_list)
              4 CALL_FUNCTION            0
              6 GET_ITER
        >>    8 FOR_ITER                 4 (to 14)
             10 STORE_NAME               1 (value)

  3          12 JUMP_ABSOLUTE            8
        >>   14 POP_BLOCK
        >>   16 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             18 RETURN_VALUE
```